# create intersection from two or more 2d numpy arrays based on common value in one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, intersection

I have 3 numpy recarrays with following structure. 
The first column is some position (Integer) and the second column is a score (Float).

**Input:**

```
a = [[1, 5.41],
     [2, 5.42],
     [3, 12.32],
     dtype=[('position', '<i4'), ('score', '<f4')])
     ]

b = [[3, 8.41],
     [6, 7.42],
     [4, 6.32],
     dtype=[('position', '<i4'), ('score', '<f4')])
     ]

c = [[3, 7.41],
     [7, 6.42],
     [1, 5.32],
     dtype=[('position', '<i4'), ('score', '<f4')])
     ]
```

All 3 arrays contain the same amount of elements.
I am looking for an efficient way to combine these three 2d arrays into one array based on the position column.

The output arary for the example above should look like this:

**Output:**

```
output = [[3, 12.32, 8.41, 7.41],
          dtype=[('position', '<i4'), ('score1', '<f4'),('score2', '<f4'),('score3', '<f4')])]
```

Only the row with position 3 is in the output array because this position appears in all 3 input arrays.

**Update**: My naive approach would be following steps:

1. create vector of the first columns of my 3 input arrays.
2. use intersect1D to get the intersection of these 3 vectors.
3. somehow retrieve indexes for the vector for all 3 input arrays.
4. create new array with filtered rows from the 3 input arrays.

**Update2**: 
Each position value can be in one, two or all three input arrays. In my output array I only want to include rows for position values which appear in all 3 input arrays.

Comment: what if it results in positions having different numbers of values, so the array would be mis-shaped?

Comment: I am not sure If I understand. 
I can guarantee that the 3 input arrays always have the same shape/structure (N,1) and in my case I always have 3 input arrays. The output array should be of shape (X,4)

Comment: So the arrays either ALL contain a value, or NONE contain a value? i.e. you won't get 2/3 containing a value? Also, could you edit the question to create the arrays, rather than showing the repr?

Comment: no it can happen that only one or two contain the position value. 
However in the output array I only want to include rows where I have position values in all 3 input arrays. I updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach, I believe it should be reasonably fast. I think the first thing you want to do is count the number occurrences for each position. This function will handle that:

```
def count_positions(positions):
    positions = np.sort(positions)
    diff = np.ones(len(positions), 'bool')
    diff[:-1] = positions[1:] != positions[:-1]
    count = diff.nonzero()[0]
    count[1:] = count[1:] - count[:-1]
    count[0] += 1
    uniqPositions = positions[diff]
    return uniqPositions, count
```

Now using the function form above you want to take only the positions that occur 3 times:

```
positions = np.concatenate((a['position'], b['position'], c['position']))
uinqPos, count = count_positions(positions)
uinqPos = uinqPos[count == 3]
```

We will be using search sorted so we sort a b and c:

```
a.sort(order='position')
b.sort(order='position')
c.sort(order='position')
```

Now we can user search sorted to find where in each array to find each of our uniqPos:

```
new_array = np.empty((len(uinqPos), 4))
new_array[:, 0] = uinqPos
index = a['position'].searchsorted(uinqPos)
new_array[:, 1] = a['score'][index]
index = b['position'].searchsorted(uinqPos)
new_array[:, 2] = b['score'][index]
index = c['position'].searchsorted(uinqPos)
new_array[:, 3] = c['score'][index]
```

There might be a more elegant solution using dictionaries, but I thought of this one first so I'll leave that to someone else.